# How do you access the storage map for a cache class programmatically?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I'm trying to create a method that will automatically create something I can save and use later, which will let me automate data migration from one version of a class to the next.

When I compile a normal persistent class, a "storage" gets created, and I would like to be able to archive some code that would let me recreate this "old storage" so I could access an "older version" from a global and map the values into the current mapping of the class.  I have objectgenerator methods that will save a version with every record, and detect if the "current version" of the class code is different from the version saved in the data record itself, but I'm not sure how to retain what the "old" version actually looked like so I can auto-migrate the data from the "old to the new".  To do this, I'm thinking that being able to read what the current storage is at compile time, I should be able to save that value elsewhere and create a durable "version reader" so I can migrate the data forward without having to actually have the programmer do the work.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach? and if so, can anyone point me to where, at compile time, the storage values are so I can do the saving of the data?

(or should I be looking at cloning some part of the generated %Save() method chain at compile time to a version specific save attached to "something else" (not sure what, but 'something'))

This question and answer originally appeared in the InterSystems Developer Community https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-do-you-access-storage-map-cache-class-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

In a database, your most important asset is your data -- business logic and code comes a close second. There should at least be someone paying attention to the data slots for sanity, even though in most cases, there is nothing to do. At the very least, any developer adding or modifying properties should "diff" the storage definition when submitting code to the source repository. The class compiler by default will handle everything correctly.

1. The simplest and best way to move from one version of a class to the next is to keep the same storage definition. The class compiler will create slots for any new properties and is completely non-destructive and conservative. When I retire properties, I generally manually rename the storage slot and give it a prefix such as zzz. This allows me to explicitly clean up and reuse these slots later if I so choose.
2. For the type of before/after compile triggers you are looking for, I would use the RemoveProjection/CreateProjection methods of a projection class which provide "a way to customize what happens when a class is compiled or removed".
3. You can use %Dictionary.CompiledStorage and related classes(Data) to have full access to the compiled storage definition of a class.

3a. An alternate approach is to use XSLT or XML parsing to read the storage definition from the exported class definition. I would only use this alternative if you need to capture details for separate source control purposes.

4. The simplest storage definitions use $ListBuild slots and a single global node. When subclasses and collection properties are used, the default storage definition gets more complicated -- that is where you will really want to stick to the simple approach (item 1).